# JavaFx: CustomTableSkin with CustomTableHeaderRow

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I am working on a CustomTableViewSkin, where I pass some config arguments to configure my skin depending on the parameter passed to.
One of the config possibility is related to the `TableHeaderRow` which is initialized in the init method of the `ableHeaderRow` which is called in the constructor.
Since I am forced to call the super constructor, there aren't my config parameters yet initialized, and even if I `@Override` the `createTableHeaderRow()` it doesn't really work as I need.

I found a solution or better said, a workaround but I'm not sure how safe is it to use.

Here is a simple code, which shows what I mean.

```
public class MyTableSkin<T> extends TableViewSkin<T> {

    private Set<Param> params;

    public MyTableSkin(TableView<T> tableView, Set<Param> params) {
        super(tableView);
        this.params = params;
    }

    @Override
    protected TableHeaderRow createTableHeaderRow() {
        // NPE at params since this method is called in super constructor there params are not initialized.
        if (params.contains(Param.TABLE_HEADER)) {
            return new MyTableHeaderRow(this);
        }
        return super.createTableHeaderRow();
    }

    private static class MyTableHeaderRow extends TableHeaderRow {

        public MyTableHeaderRow(TableViewSkinBase skin) {
            super(skin);
        }
    }

    public enum Param {
        TABLE_HEADER
    }
}
```

After a little bit experimenting I found this way:

```
public class MyTableSkin<T> extends TableViewSkin<T> {

    private Set<Param> params;

    public MyTableSkin(TableView<T> tableView, Set<Param> params) {
        super(tableView);
        this.params = params;
        getChildren().clear(); // if I didn't do this an exception is thrown
        // calling init again to "reinitialize" the skin.
        super.init(tableView); // how safe is this? :)
    }

    @Override
    protected TableHeaderRow createTableHeaderRow() {
        // Now it enters the if after the second init call, after params are initialized.
        if (params != null && params.contains(Param.TABLE_HEADER)) {
            return new MyTableHeaderRow(this);
        }
        return super.createTableHeaderRow();
    }

    private static class MyTableHeaderRow extends TableHeaderRow {

        public MyTableHeaderRow(TableViewSkinBase skin) {
            super(skin);
        }
    }

    public enum Param {
        TABLE_HEADER
    }
}
```

This way it works and I get my new fancy `table header, however I see the init has a lot of things in it, it does the listener initialization and many other stuff.

The main question is: is this way safe? Do I have to worry about the other stuff which is done in the init, or simply ignore them? I am thinking about the double registering the listeners for example.

If this is not so safe, or at all, I would suggest any modification to my code, or even a completely new solution which allows me to customize the header if a param is set. This custom skin is not only for the header. `params` could contain a lot of configurations which can be done to the skin, so I cannot really create a new skin for every configuration/parameter.

Comment: not safe at all ... don't call init methods more than once, you are calling for trouble ;) Instead, set the parameters to the Table - the skinnable is accessible "very early", as it is set in SkinBase constructor

Comment: I thought it is not so :D But since I didn't have any replacement and this was the only "working" one I used it. Yet I'm rewriting it to have that in the `skinnable` and Ill try it out.

Comment: It works fine, If you want you can post your suggestion as an answer so I can reward it ;)